# MATLAB Piecewise Functions + Vector Manipulation

Tags: matlab, function, vector

I would like to write a program which plots the points on top of a semicircle on a certain interval and a straight line everywhere else. Something like this: `__n__`.

I defined a time domain, which was stored as a vector (`t = 0:0.01:5`). I assumed that I could define the points on the top of the semicircle using elements of the time vector:

```
if t>=2|t<=2.3
y = sqrt(.15^2-(t-2.15)^2);
```

but MATLAB produced an error message saying only square matrices can be squared.

I tried to utilize indices to show that I wanted to square an element of the t vector and not the whole vector:

```
i = [200:230];
for t(200:230)
y = sqrt(.15^2-(t(i)-2.15)^2);
```

After these failures, I noticed that squaring a square matrix with one column of non-zero elements would produce a new square matrix with a column of the first matrix's elements squared. If there is some way to eliminate the extra columns of zeros after squaring the matrix, I could use that property of matrices to square the values of the t vector.

What is the simplest and most effective way to address this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to draw a horizontal line with a semicircular "bump" on it. Here's how you can do this:

```
t = 0:0.01:5;        % Create the time vector
y = zeros(size(t));  % Create a zero vector the same size as t
index = find((t >= 2) & (t <= 2.3));        % Find a set of indices into t
y(index) = sqrt(.15^2-(t(index)-2.15).^2);  % Add the "bump" to y
y(1:index(1)) = y(index(1));                % Add the line before the "bump"
y(index(end):end) = y(index(end));          % Add the line after the "bump"
```

In the above solution, the lines before and after the "bump" could be slightly higher or lower than one another (depending on where your samples in `t` fall). If you want to make sure they are at the same height, you can instead do the following:

```
index = (t >= 2) & (t <= 2.3);              % Find a set of logical indices
y(index) = sqrt(.15^2-(t(index)-2.15).^2);  % Add the "bump" to y
% OPTION #1:
y(~index) = y(find(index,1,'first'));  % Use the first circle point as the height
% OPTION #2:
y(~index) = y(find(index,1,'last'));   % Use the last circle point as the height
```

Finally, you can plot the line:

```
plot(t,y);
```

Comment: This explanation has been helpful. The following is the code I compiled:

`%DEFINE COMPONENTS OF TRANSFER FUNCTION:
north = 1.31*10^6*[1 13.3];
south = [1 516.1 5.685*10^4 1.307*10^6 1.733*10^7];
h = tf(north,south);
%TIME INTERVAL:
 t = 0:0.01:5;        

%DEFINE POINTS ON SPEED BUMP USING PIECEWISE FUNCTION:
y = zeros(size(t));  
index = find((t >= 2) & (t <= 2.3));        
y(index) = sqrt(.15^2-(t(index)-2.15).^2);  
y([1:index(1) index(end):end]) = y(index(1));
 
%PLOT PIECEWISE FUNCTION WITH RESPONSE:
lsim(h,y,t);`

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Hold on, so your question is, you want to square each element of a vector? All you have to do is:

`t.^2`

The `.` represents an [element-wise operation in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f0-40063.html#f0-38140) on a vector or an array.

And secondly, if I understood your problem currently, you want to create a vector y, which contains a function of elements of `t` such that `t>=2 | t <=2.3`?

If so, all you have to do is this:

`y = sqrt(0.15^2-(t( (t>=2|t<=2.3) )-2.15).^2));`

Essentially, I created a logical index `(t>=2 | t<=2.3)` and used to access only those elements (which I wanted) in `t`.

Also, I didn't fully understand **what** you wanted to achieve. Do you want to plot the topmost point (maxima) of a semicircular curve?

Comment: The combination of these two answers has helped me a great deal. I wanted to plot a straight line which goes into the points of a semicircle and goes back into a straight line along with the response a car chassis would have to driving over a speed bump (modeled by the semicircle). Without your t.^2 explanation I would have assumed that the '.' in the other answer was a typo.
THANK YOU BOTH!