# Function plotting in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have the following function:

```
f(t) = 0                  if    t < 0     
f(t) = 2*t^2 - 4*t +3     if   1 <= t < 2   
f(t) = Cos(t)             if    2 <= t
```

I am a new MATLAB user, and I do not how to plot the function on a single figure over the range 0<=t<=5.

Any ideas about What I have to do?

Comment: This basically sounds like a duplicate of these other questions: [How can I create a piecewise inline function in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/796072/52738), [MATLAB Piecewise Functions + Vector Manipulation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1549888/52738), [How do I perform statements on the dependent variable of a graph in matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4357995/52738)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for your help but I could not implement any code or commands to get the answer. Instead of, I was lucky and I found an example and the MATLAB commands are as follow:

```
x=linspace(0,5,3000);
y=(0*x).*(x<1) + (2*(x.^2)-(4.*x)+3).*((1<=x) & (x<2))
+ (cos(x)).*(2<=x);
plot(x,y, '.'), grid
axis([0 5 -2 4])
title ('Plot of f(t)'), xlabel('t'), ylabel('f(t)')
```

Answer (score 5):

Write a [function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/function.html) for your Laplace formula.

*Something like this*

```
function [ft] = func(t)
    if t <= 0
        ft = 0;
    elseif t > 0 &&  t < 2
        ft = 2 * t^2 - 4 * t + 3;
    elseif t >= 2
        ft = cos(t);
    end
```

You can then plot the function with [fplot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fplot.html), the second parameter defines the plotting range.

```
fplot('func', [0, 5])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean limiting x axis, then after using plot use

```
xlim([xmin xmax])
```

In your case

```
xlim([0 5])
```

Use `ylim` for limiting y axis

---

Ok, I think I  misunderstood you

Also I think, you've made mistake in your formulas

f(t) = 0 if 0<= t < 1
f(t) = 2*t^2 - 4*t +3 if 1 <= t < 2
f(t) = Cos(t) if 2 <= t

```
figure;
hold on;
x = 0:0.1:0.9;  y = 0 * x;                      plot( x, y );
x = 1:0.1:1.9;  y = 2 * x * x - 4 * x + 3;      plot( x, y );
x = 2:0.1:5;    y = cos( x );                   plot( x, y );
```